# Using Parse in replace of a Constants.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm building an app that uses quite a few constants, these are UUID's that don't change typically, there is some information in there that might change. That would be driven by our hardware guys though.

I was thinking of using parse in replace of a Constants.h file, but in my limited testing I'm having trouble getting the data from localstore when a network connection is not present.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Have a online copy of static keys that syncs to the localstore for offline availability?

What I've tried:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:className];

[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId
                             block:^(PFObject *cloudUpdate, NSError *error) {


                                 cloudUpdate[settingsName] = updateValue;
                                 [cloudUpdate pinInBackground];
                                 [cloudUpdate saveEventually];

                             }];
```

To Retrieve it:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Settings"];
[query fromLocalDatastore];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *settings, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", settings);
}];
```

I've tried using the fromLocalDataStore.
I've removed the pinned object and tried it again.

My project is setup correctly, I have local datastore enabled in my appdelegate and libsqlite3 is installed.

Comment: Oh Right. So the behavior I'm getting is: When wifi or cellular is enabled. It works fine, when no network is present it won't give me a value at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use user defaults. A simple config to register your built in / hard coded values initially and a query that you run periodically to update them.